# Update Pandas dataframe value based on present value

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe, multiplication

I have a Pandas dataframe with values which should lie between, say, `11-100`. However, sometimes I'll have values between `1-10`, and this is because the person who was entering that row used a convention that the value in question should be multiplied by 10. So what I'd like to do is run a Pandas command which will fix those particular rows by multiplying their value by `10`.

I can reference the values in question by doing something like

```
my_dataframe[my_dataframe['column_name']<10]
```

and I could set them all to a particular value, like 50, like so

```
my_dataframe[my_dataframe['column_name']<10] = 50
```

but how do I set them to a value which is 10* the value of that particular row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
my_dataframe[my_dataframe['column_name']<10] *= 10
```

Comment: Glad can help you!